# jQuery val() puts correct number in input field but tags still show no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, laravel-4

I'm trying to have jQuery update a field based on inputs fields on an order form. I used jQuery's val() to get set the value but when I try to validate the order form with Laravel 4's Validator:: it says the field is empty. When I inspected the field I saw that despite having the correct number in the input field there still was no value actually assigned to the field. How can I use jQuery's val() to set a value that Laravel 4's Validator:: will be able to see and recognize as being a legitimate input? If anyone could explain where I went wrong or show me how to correctly do this it would be very much appreciated! Thank you so much!

Here is the relevant jQ snip, when the page loads num = 1 because there will always be at least 1 page:

```
var num = 1;
$('#number_of_pages').val(num);
```

And here is the last bit of the snippet to update the number of pages if the user clicks the AddPage button:

```
/*Update number of pages*/
var updated_number_of_pages = $('.inputPage').length;
$('#number_of_pages').val(updated_number_of_pages);
```

And for when they click the DeletePage button:

```
/*Updated Number of pages*/
var updated_number = $('.inputPage').length;
$('#number_of_pages').val(updated_pages);
```

And here is the View:

```
{{ Form::text('number_of_pages', null, array('id' => 'number_of_pages')) }}
    @if($errors->has('number_of_pages'))
        {{ $errors->first('number_of_pages') }}
    @endif
```

And the relevant part of the Controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
               array(
                'order_name'      => 'required',
                'phone'           => 'required|min:10|numeric',
                'email'           => 'required',
                'st_address'      => 'required',
                'post_date'       => 'required',
                'number_of_pages' => 'required',
               )            
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'm a little confused about the question but you may use `attr` to set the attribute in the source:

```
$('#number_of_pages').attr('value', updated_number_of_pages);
```

So, you can see the changes in the source, `val()` sets the property in the memory.

**Update:**

Also make sure your form is opened using `Form::open()` and the `text` field is inside the form, something like this:

```
{{ Form::open(...) }}
    {{ Form::input('number_of_pages') }}
    {{-- Rest of the code --}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify when I use val() or attr() to set the value of an input field the field itself shows the correct number but when I inspect the element or if I submit the order form both the inspector and the validator both show no value attributed to the input field. So the problem is that even though it is showing the correct input I cannot submit my form because it is not passing the validation rules I have created.

Comment: When you submit the form try to check the inputs by `dd(Input::all())` and make sure that field is available and have value, try using both `attr` and `val`.

Comment: Ah, okay, it was not in the dd(Input::all()). I then went back and used both
 $('#number_of_pages').attr('value', updated_number_of_pages);
and 
 `$('#number_of_pages').val(updated_number_of_pages);`
and ran dd(Input::all()) again and the input number_of_pages is still not there.

Comment: Are you sure about this ? Make sure you are just not refreshing the old submission, try to submit it from the beginning because it should be there.

Comment: Just double checked, it is not showing up in the dd();

Comment: Out of my knowledge :(

Comment: I'm guessing its a weird Laravel 4 thing.

Comment: What if you don't do anything using `jQuery` and submit directly with some value in it.

Comment: Hmmm. Even if I do it manually, just creating the input and writing it in, when I submit it it is not there.

Comment: If you want to put that as the answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: So it looks like I was using the Input:: wrong. I had thought that the Input:: was for any input but now it looks like it is only for those inside a form. So since the input was create outside the form the reason it didn't have a value to validate was because Laravel couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes, the `form` is used to hold all the inputs/elements that's the reason a form exists primarily, as a container/shell of elements, +1 ed already :-)